# How do I create a remote location?

Tags: 11.10, remote, bluefish

So here is my deal. I'm thinking about using Bluefish to do remote file editing (PHP, HTML, Js etc) on our webserver. This is pretty easy with a program like Dreamweaver that has FTP capability built in but I don't see a program that can do this on Linux (at least not one that is freely available). So I was thinking that I could create a remote location in Ubuntu and then hopefully the remote directory would appear in the Bluefish navigation area.

What do you guys think?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but similar to MS Windows you can open Nautilus, then File, then Connect to Server.  There you can setup a remote location.

Comment: I've moved this to an answer so if it is what you are looking for then please accept it.  Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

you are going to get a number of suggestions for this. IMO I prefer ssh as it is more secure then ftp.

### Bluefish

Not exactly what you want, but if you like bluefish I would download the file, edit it locally, and then upload it back to the server.

### vim/gvim

The reason I mention vim is that, although there is a bit of a learning curve, it is a powerful editor and so helpful on servers.

You may need to install these applications

```
sudo apt-get install vim vim-gnome
```

You can edit files over ssh or ftp with vim or if you prefer a graphical interface gvim.

```
# command line
vim scp://user@server//file/to/edit

# Graphical
gvim scp://user@server//file/to/edit
```

Notice the two `//` ;p

### sshfs

You can also use sshfs to mount the remote directory and then you could open the file with bluefish.

Install `sshfs`

```
sudo apt-get install sshfs
```

Add your user to the fuse group

Then mount the remove file system in your home directory

```
# Use any name for the mount you wish
mkdir ~/web_server

# mount the remote directory
# keep the syntax 'idmap=user'
# id@server = your login_name@server

sshfs -0 idmap=user id@server:/var/www ~/web_server
```

You then can use bluefish, or any editor you wish to edit files in ~/web_server

See [ubuntu wiki sshfs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS)

From windows you can use winscp

Comment: I appreciate the help. But I need to use an editor like Bluefish. In fact Bluefish isn't even the editor I want to use, I'm tempted to try and install the program I use for Windows through Wine but I thought I'd try some native linux programs first.

I'd rather just try and have a remote location added to Ubuntu, I don't mind using SSH versus FTP but the problem remains the same **How do you set this up with Unity**

Comment: What operating system is the remote system running? Most Linux and Unix systems that allow remote access will run SSH servers, and you can connect via Connect to Server using SFTP, a secure version of FTP that is part of an SSH suite. See the Ubuntu guide to (SSH)[https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH].

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but similar to MS Windows you can open Nautilus, then File, then Connect to Server. There you can setup a remote location.

Comment: this is also a nice option, sshfs is similar, you can add an entry in fstab for sshfs, mount a specific directory, and map users. So one may then edit files in `/var/www` as a local user.